# How to tag specific input files from different directories

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am reading two set of directories (let's say dirA and dirt) as inputs to my MapReduce jobs and I need to tag them differently in some way so that during map phase I know which is from which. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could investigate using [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html) and define a different mapper for each input path, or examine the input split ([Context.getInputSplit()](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MapContext.html#getInputSplit%28%29) - cast it to a FileSplit and get the path) and adjust the output accordingly.